# Case change of OCX control name in VB6

Tags: vb6, ocx

In VB6, when the project is saved, the case of the declaration of OCX control change in the .FRM so the source control report some changes that are not in fact :

```
-Object = "{FDFCEE46-937A-11D4-B73C-00104BAFEBDD}#1.0#0"; "OmniTBox.ocx"
+Object = "{FDFCEE46-937A-11D4-B73C-00104BAFEBDD}#1.0#0"; "omniTBox.ocx"

-Object = "{253FB3DC-6581-4D7E-ADA0-0C93062AB59C}#3.0#0"; "GPBUTTONSH.ocx"
+Object = "{253FB3DC-6581-4D7E-ADA0-0C93062AB59C}#3.0#0"; "gpbuttonsh.ocx"
```

Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: VB6 is not a case-sensitive language.  You need a smarter source control product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the case in the registry.
For example search the value :

```
"253FB3DC-6581-4D7E-ADA0-0C93062AB59C" (or "gpbuttonsh.ocx")
```

in your registry and change the case to GPBUTTONSH.ocx everywhere (but it should be enough with the HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib one) then VB6 will write it like that in the project.